# Copy list items from one sharepoint server to another programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to copy a sharepoint list from one server to another server?

So I have server A running site 1, I want to copy the list from ServerA-Site1 to ServerB-Site1.

I've seen numerous articles on SO, to copy from one site to another as long as the sites are on the same server.

I've already looked at several articles like: [Programmatically copying custom content type and columns from one web to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800485/programmatically-copying-custom-content-type-and-columns-from-one-web-to-another)

[copy list items from one list to another in sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075323/copy-list-items-from-one-list-to-another-in-sharepoint)

From the looks of things, it does not seem possible but I'd like confirmation or direction to a possible answer (if I wasn't looking in the right areas)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537247%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

But it can be tricky because of some special field types (for example, metadata field or person or group field).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can define two **client context** for each of your site and then get the required lists and update them using some variables. This should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

See the content migration API:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453426.ASPX

You should be able to export items, transport them to the second server, then import them.